# Difference between let, fun and function in F#

Tags: function, f#, functional-programming

I'm learning F# and I cannot figure out what the difference between let, fun and function is, and my text book doesn't really explain that either. As an example:

```
 let s sym = function
 | V x -> Map.containsKey x sym
 | A(f, es) -> Map.containsKey f sym && List.forall (s sym) es;;
```

Couldn't I have written this without the `function` keyword? Or could I have written that with `fun` instead of `function`? And why do I have to write `let` when I've seen some examples where you write

```
fun s x = 
...
```

What's the difference really?

Comment: It'd be a bit easier to show you alternatives if you also tell us what `V` and `A` are.

Comment: "function" is a kind of "match" that comes into its own in pipeline expressions.  e.g. x |> function | case1 -> ... | case2 -> ...   It's a nice style.

Answer (score 25):

I guess you should really ask [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229(v=vs.110).aspx), but in a nutshell:

**`let`** binds a value with a symbol. The value can be a plain type like an `int` or a `string`, but it can also be a function. In FP functions are values and can be treated in the same way as those types.

**`fun`** is a keyword that introduces an anonymous function - think lambda expression if you're familiar with C#.

Those are the two important ones, in the sense that all the others usages you've seen can be thought as syntax sugar for those two. So to define a function, you can say something like this:

```
 let myFunction = 
     fun firstArg secondArg ->
        someOperation firstArg secondArg
```

And that's very clear way of saying it. You declare that you have a function and then bind it to the `myFunction` symbol.

But you can save yourself some typing by just conflating anonymous function declaration and binding it to a symbol with `let`:

```
 let myFunction firstArg secondArg =
    someOperation firstArg secondArg
```

What `function` does is a bit trickier - you combine an anonymous single-argument function declaration with a `match` expression, by matching on an implicit argument. So these two are equivalent:

```
let myFunction firstArg secondArg =
    match secondArg with
    | "foo" -> firstArg
    | x -> x

let myFunction firstArg = function
    | "foo" -> firstArg
    | x -> x
```

If you're just starting on F#, I'd steer clear of that one. It has its uses (mainly for providing succinct higher order functions for maps/filters etc.), but results in code less readable at a glance.

Answer (score 18):

These things are sort of shortcuts to each other.

The most fundamental thing is `let`. This keyword gives names to stuff:

```
let name = "stuff"
```

Speaking more technically, the `let` keyword defines an identifier and binds it to a value:

```
let identifier = "value"
```

After this, you can use words `name` and `identifier` in your program, and the compiler will know what they mean. Without the `let`, there wouldn't be a way to name stuff, and you'd have to always write all your stuff inline, instead of referring to chunks of it by name.

Now, values come in different flavors. There are strings `"some string"`, there are integer numbers `42`, floating point numbers `5.3`, Boolean values `true`, and so on. One special kind of value is *function*. Functions are also values, in most respects similar to strings and numbers. But how do you write a function? To write a string, you use double quotes, but what about function?

Well, to write a function, you use the special word `fun`:

```
let squareFn = fun x -> x*x
```

Here, I used the `let` keyword to define an identifier `squareFn`, and bind that identifier to a value of the function kind. Now I can use the word `squareFn` in my program, and the compiler will know that whenever I use it I mean a function `fun x -> x*x`.

This syntax is technically sufficient, but not always convenient to write. So in order to make it shorter, the `let` binding takes an extra responsibility upon itself and provides a shorter way to write the above:

```
let squareFn x = x*x
```

That should do it for `let` vs `fun`.

Now, the `function` keyword is just a short form for `fun` + `match`. Writing `function` is equivalent to writing `fun x -> match x with`, period.

For example, the following three definitions are equivalent:

```
let f = fun x -> 
  match x with 
  | 0 -> "Zero"
  | _ -> "Not zero"
 
let f x =  // Using the extra convenient form of "let", as discussed above
  match x with 
  | 0 -> "Zero"
  | _ -> "Not zero"
 
let f = function  // Using "function" instead of "fun" + "match"
  | 0 -> "Zero"
  | _ -> "Not zero"
```